# Zenfone 2 stuck on USB logo

Tags: device-firmware, asus-zenfone-2

I tried to flash Zenfone 2 but instead of writing `droidboot.img` I sent an `.exe` file. And now when I try to get into droidboot (Volume + Power button) the device gets stuck at USB logo.

Whatsoever I found online is related to Zenfone 4|5|6 and not Zenfone 2

How can I access droidboot again ?

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Wow, this sounds a little bit like a hard brick. Were you ever able to recover the phone?

Answer (score -1):

Long press the power button. Phone will turn off. Then press power button and volume up button simultaneously, till the asus logo appears. Then you will enter the recovery mode. Reboot from there(press power button after navigating to reboot using volum up/down)

Comment: I already explained ,there is no recovery mode because I already erased it in a previous attempt7 to rewrite it, but i used a wrong file to rewrite, so the recovery mode is gone and the phone never enters in